# Alternate function of public_path() in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am looking for any alternate function to upload/store file in folder. public_path was working fine untill I moved public folder content to root folder.

I tried to find solution but none working, may be old solutions, not applicable to laravel 8.

IS there any function which can be use as an alternate of public_path which will store image to any folder available in root of project?

Comment: use bash_path()

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Got this, `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\bash_path()`

Comment: it's helper function (it's a global function) see this link 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#paths-method-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `register()` method  on `AppServiceProvider` :

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('../public_html'); // you given path from root
    });
}
```

Comment: Where I can find `AppServiceProvider `. Sorry, I am new in laravel.

Comment: its located on `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

Comment: I tried your solution but file didn't get upload in folder. This is what path I received  `D:\xampp\htdocs\vaiseshika\webapp\../public_html\/dashboard_assets/files
` from this function `public_path('/dashboard_assets/files')`. I want to store file in `root/dashboard_assets/files` as shown in function. But why file didn't upload, any idea?

Comment: Okay I figured it out.... I just replace `return base_path('../public_html')` to this `return base_path('../public_html')`. Here did only one change which is, change folder name (`public_html`) to my folder which was present in root folder `dashboard_assets`. And all worked now

Comment: Just one last question, I did made modification in code function. Will those changes be safe when I will update laravel version. I mean those modification will not get override after laravel update, right?

Comment: When you update the laravel version, it will change the `vendor` directory, and your development directory like app, config, database, public, resources, routes will remain same, it wont affect this folder.